# Postgresql: "no password supplied" error in rails although login in psql is OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I created new user 'deploy' for database with certain password and then created database 'deploy_production'.

In my rails app, database is configured as follows:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
production:
  <<: *default
  database: deploy_production
  username: deploy
  password: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Db password is correctly set in console trough:

```
export DATABASE_PASSWORD=actual_password
```

Password is correct because I am able to login with it to psql:

```
psql -d deploy_production -U deploy
```

But when I run rails app using Thin, in production enviroment, and the request comes, following error appears:

```
PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied):
activerecord (4.2.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:655:in `initialize'
...
```

What is interesting - commands `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:setup` and `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` work perfectly.

This is my pg_hba.conf:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     md5
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Do you have any clues what could cause the problem?

Comment: Have you tried putting the password in the config file directly, to check if its an environment issue?

Comment: it could be that environment variable isnt passed.

Comment: You're right, it is problem with environment var. How to fix it? I dont wanna store password directly in file...

Comment: try to add host: localhost to the database.yml

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'm having a similar problem and I wanted to check what OS you were using before I posted my solution as a proper answer.

Comment: No, it was Linux. After some time I managed to do some sort of workaround but I don't remember what exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should setup you env variable in the .bashrc file (or .bash_profile) depending on the linux that you are using.

.bashrc

> export DATABASE_PASSWORD=actual_password